# Calling a variable through a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to Python and I've been reading some things about Tkinter and I find it really interesting; that said I have a problem with this code I have. I have this program that makes the computer pick a random number between 1 and 10 and you have to guess the number; yes, really simple; and since no new int is generated after a wrong attempt or a right attempt I want to make a button that generates a new random number when it had been clicked. I saw some solutions with 'Class' stuff but I'm not really familiar with it yet but if that's the best solution for my problem, well, I gotta see.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

random_number = random.randint(1, 10)


def retrieve_input(event):
    inp = float(number_space.get())
    if inp == random_number:
        print("You got it!")
    else:
        print("That's not the number.")
        print("The number was {}".format(random_number) + '.')



number = Label(root, text="Guess a number between 1 and 10:")
number.grid(row=0)
number_space = Entry(root)
number_space.grid(row=0, column=1)
butt = Button(root, text="Generate a new random number")
butt.grid(row=1, column=0)


number_space.bind("<Return>", retrieve_input)




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You didn't want to just move `random_number = random.randint(1, 10)` into the `retrieve_input` function?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, I could but I wanted to make the button just to learn more stuff about this. It would be easier to just delete the button and move random_number to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a button to generate a new random number as you can do that when the user enters their answer. The button could just restart the game by clearing the entry box. So as soon as the user hits Return, a random number is generated at that point, and then the logic checks whether their answer == that new random number.

This would happen every time the user enters something, so it negates the need to have a separate button for number generation

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()

def retrieve_input(event):
    random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    inp = float(number_space.get())
    if inp == random_number:
        print("You got it!")
    else:
        print("That's not the number.")
        print("The number was {}".format(random_number) + '.')

def startAgain():
    number_space.delete(0, 'end')


number = Label(root, text="Guess a number between 1 and 10:")
number.grid(row=0)
number_space = Entry(root)
number_space.grid(row=0, column=1)
butt = Button(root, text="Generate a new random number", command=startAgain)
butt.grid(row=1, column=0)

number_space.bind("<Return>", retrieve_input)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

i would restructer some of your code because you are wanting to be able to generate the random number in several places in your code it would be better to put it in a sub then call that sub whenever you want a new random integer and then just return the value.

```
def randomnumgen():
    random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    return random_number
```

then when you are calliing the subroutine do the value that you want it to be stored in then = nameofsubroutine

```
num = randomnumgen()
```

Comment: ... or maybe the minimal change of `random_number = lambda: random.randint(1, 10)` (and calling as `random_number()` instead of using as a variable).

Comment: i did not think of that, that would probably be better